# Needs upper bound in for loop to be saved in extra variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, upperbound

I see that often in older code

```
DWORD num = someOldListImplementation.GetNum();
for (DWORD i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    someOldListImplementation.Get(i);
}
```

rather than

```
   for (DWORD i = 0; i < someOldListImplementation.GetNum(); i++)
   {
        someOldListImplementation.Get(i);
   }
```

I guess the first implementation should prevent calls to `GetNum()` on each cycle. But, are there cases that the compiler in C++11 does some optimization to the second code snippet which makes the `num` variable obsolete?

Should I always prefer the first implementation?

If that question duplicates another question for 100%, tell me and close this one. No problem.

Comment: Only if the compiler can prove that `GetNum()` returns the *same* value for all iterations. And that could be simple ... or very very complex...depending on how `GetNum()` is defined, and what you're doing in the `for` loop itself.

Comment: Also, there is third impl: `for (DWORD i = 0, num = x.GetNum(); i < num; i++) {  .... }`. That is, **limit** the *scope* of the variable `num`.

Comment: @Nawaz Equals your third implementation my first one?

Comment: Not exactly the same. In the third impl, `num` does *not* exist outside the loop, which is an improvement over the first impl!

Comment: @Nawaz Your third impl seems to fulfill all requirements: 1st prevent calls to `GetNum()` on each cycle. 2nd: Have the `num` not outside of the loop. I'd consider this impl as prefered one!

Comment: If you have [Range](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) like library, you can use a fourth one : `for(auto i : view::ints(0, x.GetNum())) { ... }`. You can design such utilities yourself as well.

Comment: It is nice, for instance if you add elements to the list. In cases where you don't need that extra effort, just calling a method that returns an int without much calculations should not be problematic in terms of performances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer to my question is to use

```
for (auto i = 0, num = x.GetNum(); i < num; ++i) 
{ 

}
```

because

- it prevent calls to `GetNum()` on each cycle
- variable `num` is not exposed outside of the loop

*Credits go to user Nawaz!*

I also used ++i instead of i++. Reason: https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-it-matter-if-we-use-I++-or-++I-for-a-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

The C++ (C++11 in this case) standard doesn't *seem* to leave much room for this. It states explicitly in `6.5.3 The for statement /1` that (my emphasis):

> the condition specifies a test, ***made before each iteration,*** such that the loop is exited when the condition becomes false;

However, as stated in `1.9 Program execution /1`:

> Conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.
>
> This provision is sometimes called the "as-if" rule, because an implementation is free to disregard *any* requirement of this International Standard as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program.

So, if an implementation can ascertain that the return value from `GetNum()` will not change during the loop, it can quite freely optimise all but the first call out of existence.

Whether an implementation *can* ascertain that depends on a great many things, and that number of things seems to expand with each new iteration of the standard. The things I'm thinking of are volatility, access from multiple threads, `constexpr` and so on.

You may well have to work rather *hard* to notify the compiler that it is free to do this (and, even then, it's not *required* to do so).

The only problem I can see with the first code sample you have is that `num` may exist for longer than is necessary (if its reason for existence is only to manage this loop). However, this can easily be fixed by explicitly restricting the scope, such as with the "small-change":

```
{
    DWORD num = someOldListImplementation.GetNum();
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        someOldListImplementation.Get(i);
    }
}
// That num is no longer in existence.
```

or by incorporating it into the `for` statement itself:

```
for (DWORD num = someOldListImplementation.GetNum(), i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    someOldListImplementation.Get(i);
}
// That num is no longer in existence.
```