# How does gcc identify "possibly infinite loops"?

Tags: c, gcc

I had been receiving warnings about loops in my C code when `-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations` is enabled:

`warning: cannot optimize possibly infinite loops [-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations]`

The warning seems to be very finnicky, and is difficult to reproduce in a minimal example (beyond trivally-obvious infinite loops). Moving to a new compiler version also changed the warning behavior. This led me to wondering about how the warning is actually implemented.

The [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says:

> Warn if the loop cannot be optimized because the compiler cannot assume anything on the bounds of the loop indices. With -funsafe-loop-optimizations warn if the compiler makes such assumptions.

I can't find any documentation on how exactly GCC makes assumptions about the bounds of the loop indices. I have seen other questions about specific cases where this warning was emitted, but I am asking about how the compiler determines whether to emit it or not in general. Clang doesn't have this warning, and the similar [clang-tidy `bugprone-infinite-loops`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-infinite-loop.html) clearly spells out the criteria for warning.

Comment: This usually happens when you use an `unsigned` variable, and the condition is `variable >= 0`. Since the variable can never be negative, this condition is always true so the loop is infinite.

Comment: If you post the code that produced the warning, someone should be able to explain how the compiler identified it as infinite.

Comment: It could also happen with `i <= INT_MAX`. Again, this is always true for `int i;`

Comment: One common trap is a loop like `i <= n-1` which can fail with `unsigned` variables (as well as being harder to read than `i < n`.

Comment: "because the compiler cannot assume anything on the bounds of the loop indices" this makes me think the bounds are non local variables, i.e they could be changed outside of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, I can't share the exact code, and like I mentioned, I haven't been able to create a standalone example that triggers it. I was more interested in the general explanation anyway. 

For this particular case, I think that Jeff's note about non-local bounds is onto something, the bound is indeed an expression that uses variables declared outside the loop (but not modified within it).

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979174/3712532) seems to get close to the kind of explanation I am looking for, but for C++

Comment: Sounds like you may have a clue (from the link), but you might be able to post the error message(s). And, post a few snippets from the real code. I don't think that would break any confidentiality (e.g. 10 lines from  a 10,000 line code base)--YMMV